# Python UDP program multiple connections with select

Tags: python, select

I'm making a UDP program that connects multiple clients/neighbors. There is no server everyone is using the same program. I'm trying to test it with localhost so consider all IPs and ports of neighbors work as intended. Using 127.0.0.1 as IP on all and connecting to different ports.
So my question is why do I receive the startup data that I send before the while loop but I cannot send any? Seems that I am doing something wrong with sys.stdin.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
going = True

input = [s]
while going:

  i,o,e = select.select(input,[],[],)
  try :
    for x in i:
      if x == sys.stdin: 
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        for i in neighbors:
          addr = (i[1][0], int(i[1][1]))
          s.sendto(data, addr)
      else:
        msg, addr = s.recvfrom(100)
        print msg
  except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()   
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` is always `[s]`, so `i` is always going to be `[s]`, so `x == sys.stdin` is never going to be `True` (because `x` is always `s`), so only the `else` clause will ever execute.

Maybe you meant `input = [s, sys.stdin]`?

Comment: yeah you're probably right. And how do I do the for and if clauses instead?

Comment: It still did not work. Leaving it as it is just adding the socket in the list. There's something wrong with my if clause.